# Java - How do I copy a java aplication jar file?

Tags: java, jar

Is it possible to copy a jar file from which I'm running my application? 
How do I find a source to this jar file? 
Each user can save my application's jar file in a different folder.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Why would you want to have several copies of the program?  If you want to allow the user to change some data or configuration files, the solution is to save those files, not the entire program.

Comment: I dont won't to have several copy of program. I just want to create backup of jar file.

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand because it has one or more words missing.

Comment: I want to create a backup of application exe file. But I don't know how to set a source to this file.

Comment: **Is it possible to copy a jar file which I running my application** why do not you try to copy?

Comment: **How to find a source to this jar file**, if source is exported while creating jar, you can use 7zip or unzip the the jar and get source code.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer one part of your question: how do you find the location of your JAR at runtime:

```
File jarDir = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath());
locationOfJar = jarDir.getAbsolutePath();
```

This will give you the path to the folder the Jar is currently in as a String.

Answer (score 0):

**W**hat IDE or Compiler are you using? If you are using Eclipse you should find where your saves go and check your package, there you'll find the .jar and the .java forms of your application.